# Once soft, suspicious

Tags: riddle

> Once soft, suspicious
>   Once heavenly, harsh
>   Once a dream, a danger
>   Now an elusive stash to relegate our life to

To what/who/where does this refer to?

**Hints**

> Blurs or darkens vision.

---

> Once material, now immaterial

---

> Once in the air, now on the web

Comment: Can I check whether you actually mean "relegate" rather than, say, "regulate"? Usually "relegate" needs an indirect object, to say where whatever-it-is is being relegated *to*. (E.g., a sports team might be relegated to a lower division; a company employee might be relegated to a post doing boring ill-paid work in a remote outpost.)

Comment: I definitely did not mean "regulate". I used "relegate" in the sense "to assign to a place of insignificance" or maybe "to send into exile", as I found in some dictionaries. However, I am not that fluent in English, and "relegate" could have a connotation I am not aware of.

Comment: No, that's fine. It isn't common to see "relegate" without "to" -- of all the examples in the OED, only one is lacking it -- but I can't actually think of a good substitute. "Exile" would do but I guess doesn't quite match your meaning.

Comment: To make it grammatically correct, should it read "Now an elusive stash to relegate our life **to**" ? Or something in the same idea ?

Comment: Only if you mean that the elusive stash is where our life is relegated to. If you mean it's what does the relegating, you'd need to say "to insignificance", "to hell", "to the Falkland Islands", or whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a

> Cloud

Once soft, suspicious

> A cloud is soft but also can mean under a cloud of suspicion

Once heavenly, harsh

> Clouds are heavenly objects in the sky but also can bring rain

Once a dream, a danger

> A cloud is obscure, dreamy but also can bring a storm

Now an elusive stash to relelegate our life to

> Cloud computing - use of computer technology stored on servers rather than the client computers

Hints:

> Cloud also means 
>  Blurs or darkens vision - to cloud  
>  Once material, now immaterial - After raining it can disappear  
>  Once in the air, now on the web - now can refer to cloud computing

Comment: @crybaba "The cloud" is immaterial (even if stored on material storage); rain *can* be harsh, especially in the form of a storm; this all made sense to me, even the dream part – if need be, one can go as far as a thought bubble for this one (which looks like a cloud), but I think of clouds and dreams as metaphors for each other in general. If you're not getting it, I think it's you who is forcing that.

Answer (score 8):

i think it is:

> **angel's trumpet**

Once soft, suspicious

> it is a soft and weird plant

Once heavenly, harsh

> angel is heavenly and trumpets are harsh

Once a dream, a danger

> this is a hallucinating plant and it is poisonous so dangerous

Now an elusive stash to relegate our life

> it is used in medicine or to get high

Comment: Oohh nice answer !  But not the one I had in mind. The "elusive stash" part is not very convincing though.

Answer (score 7):

Probably wrong, but I'll post it anyway. Is it:

> A (kidnapper's) blindfold

Once soft, *(now)* suspicious

> A blindfold is usually made of comfortable soft fabric.
>  Now that you have been kidnapped, it's suspicious that you have it on.

Once heavenly, *(now)* harsh

> A blindfold is sometimes used for 'bedroom role-play' which can be seen as heavenly.
>  Now it's harsh the kidnapper used a blindfold that once pleasured you.

Once a dream, *(now)* a danger

> Some people sleep (better) using a blindfold.
>  Now you're in danger because of the kidnapper.

Now an elusive stash to relegate our life

> The kidnapper now controls your life, and decides whether you live/die and if you are being released or not.

Hint

> The purpose of a blindfold is to blur/darken vision.

Comment: Good ideas, but not very convincing on "heavenly", IMO. Note that the (now)s are not intended to be on each sentence's second part.

Comment: @fffred "Note that the (now)s are not intended to be on each sentence's second part." I know. I tried to come up with something else. I think it has something to do with a medicine / drug / poison, since a lot of them has the side-effect to blur vision, but I couldn't come up with something in that direction. As I said "Probably wrong, ..", but I can't come up with anything else atm, and my knowledge of medicine / drugs / poisons are close to zip, let alone in English (I'm Dutch myself). :) If I can come up with something else I'll post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Medicine, drug, poison. Dead ends ...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Ash/Ashes

Once soft, suspicious

> I got nothing

Once heavenly, harsh

> Used in Hindu rituals (Vibhuti)

Once a dream, a danger

> Farm land with ashy soil at the base of volcanoes were great for crops, but you had to watch out for the active volcano

Now an elusive stash to relegate our life

> After death, some people want to be cremated

With the hint (Blurs or darkens vision)

> Getting ash in you eye can blur you vision or ashes can obscure the sun and darken everything around you

Comment: Interesting ideas, but the match is weak for "soft, suspicious" indeed. The rest is not bad, although not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is it,

> Love?

Once soft, suspicious

> Feeling of love is both soft(filled with warmth) and suspicious(false love)

Once heavenly, harsh

> Love is one of the main forces in the universe with a Goddess dedicated to it(Venus). It's also harsh(broken hearts).

Once a dream, a danger

> Being suspicious and possibly false, love is dangerous, as it's possible to deceive using love. It's also the dream of many people to fall in love with someone.

Now an elusive stash to relegate our life to

> In today's busy lives, love has become scarce. Both emotionally(stress), and physically(lack of time and mood). That's why we have to chase it, instead of it coming to us.

Comment: Nice one, but still not quite there. Is love that scarce now? Not sure, but I admit that this last verse has something a little bit nostalgic like that.

Comment: When you're a professional programmer, along with your wife, it tends to be rare.